# How to refresh the linear layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

My application has one `LinearLayout` that `LinearLayout` consists of the 3 `Linearlayouts` and that each linear layout has one `Relativelayout` and one linear layout(initially the visibility of these linear layouts is gone). If you click on the relative layout then the regarding linear layout will be displayed. But how to refresh the entire linear layout after clicking on the relative layout.

Code:

```java
private OnClickListener exit2Listener = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
       if(!exit2status)
       {
          if(RB_Constant.upcomingexits_obj.response.size() > 1)
          {
             if(RB_Constant.upcomingexits_obj.response.get(1).listRestaurants.size() > 0)
             {
                 // Create the views on the fly instead of using the ListView
                 UpcomingResultsListViewAdapter2 rbupcadapter2 = new UpcomingResultsListViewAdapter2(RB_UpcomingExits.this);
                 int numItems2 = 0;

                 if(RB_Constant.upcomingexits_obj.response.get(1).listRestaurants.size() > 0)
                 {
                    numItems2 = RB_Constant.upcomingexits_obj.response.get(1).listRestaurants.size();
                 }

                 //linearLayout2
                 for(int position=0; position < numItems2; position++)
                 {
                    View convertview = null;
                    convertview = rbupcadapter2.getView(position, convertview, null);
                    listLayout2.addView(convertview);
                 }
             }              
          }
          else
          {
             //toastMsg("No results!");
          }
          listLayout2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          exit2status=true;

          if(!exit1status || exit3status || exit4status || exit5status)
          {
             //System.out.println("exit2 GONE");
             listLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             listLayout3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             exit1status = false;
             exit3status = false;

          }

          LLExitDetails.invalidate();
       }
       else
       {
          System.out.println("exit2 GONE");
          listLayout2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          exit2status = false;

          LLExitDetails.invalidate();
       }
    }       
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Retrieve the LinearLayout that contains everything.  When you need to "refresh" it, call `invalidate`.  Only call it in the UI thread though.  If you call it in another thread (say a timer), then call `postInvalidate`.  Both cause the View's `onDraw` method to be called when the OS is ready to call it.

Comment: i added the my code please see that. In the code "LLExitDetails" is main Linear Layout. and i add the invalidate but it is not working.

Comment: not refreshing. means it's not show the first linear layout when i am call the invalidate.

Comment: If the problem is that views don't become invisible when you call .setVisibility(View.GONE), then are you sure those methods are being called?  Invalidate is how you redraw views.  Another thing to try is to call LLExitDetails.invalidate() at the end of the "onClick" method outside any if-statement to ensure it's ALWAYS called.  Then you can optimize when you have the logic of the method worked out.

Comment: is it possible to call invalidate without thread? because here i am calling the invalidate without thread.

Comment: As stated, invalidate should always be called in UI thread (which you are doing) so don't worry about that.

Comment: i am putting the invalidate end of the onclick but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time to solve this problem too.
And I found a simple method of refresh LinearLayout in 3 lines of code

You must set transperent color in style.xml

```
   <color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

And in the code just call to set background

```
   LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.noteList);
   ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
   ll.invalidate();
```

If you has drawable background call

```
  ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

To refresh view as a graphical way use invalidate it's call onDraw() and for recalculate view dimensions and any thing related to height , width , margins and padding use requestLayout it's call onMeasure()

Answer (score -2):

```
linearLayout.removeAllViews();
//The again load the linearlayout view
runLinearLayout();
```